# Bing Custom Search - how are result MetaTags formatted?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, bing-search, bing-custom-search

Given the following meta tag in a web page

```
<meta name="search.date" content="22/05/2018 00:00:00">
```

Using Bing Custom Search API to get this result, in [Page.searchTags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-custom-search-api-v7-reference#webpage), it appears as

```
"searchTags": [{
  "name": "search.date", 
  "content": "&quot;22\/05\/2018 00:00:00&quot;; 22; 05; 2018; 00; 00; 00"
}]
```

Can anybody make sense of the funny format and repeated data? There's no mention of it in the docs.